# ng-messages validation using a button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-messages

I am trying to figure out how to use ng-message based off of a button click.  Most of the documentation I have found automatically shows the error message based off an input not the button.  What would I change so the ng-messages show after the button in clicked.  Here is my code

```
<div ng-controller="userController"> 
    <div class=user>
        <form name="login">
            <h2 class>Login</h2>
            <h3 class = "login_page">UserName</h3>
            <input ng-model="user" type="text" ng-minlength="1" required>
            <h3 class = "login_page">Password</h3>
            <input ng-model="password" type="password" name="password" ng-minlength="4" required>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" ng-click="login()" >
            <div ng-messages="login.password.$error" style="color:maroon" role="alert">
                <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>
                <div ng-message="minlength">Your field is too short</div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $submitted flag on the form controller with ngIf:

```
<div ng-if="login.$submitted" ng-messages="login.password.$error" style="color:maroon" role="alert">
  <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>
  <div ng-message="minlength">Your field is too short</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-show` directive of angular with `$submitted` property of `ng-form`

Add this to your code `ng-show="login.$submitted"`

```
    <input type="submit" value="Login" ng-click="login()" >
    <div ng-show="login.$submitted" ng-messages="login.password.$error" style="color:maroon" role="alert">
        <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>
        <div ng-message="minlength">Your field is too short</div>
    </div>
```

You can see a working fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ANxmv/4147/) . Hope this will help

---

Or Alternatively add show to each message like this

```
    <div ng-messages="login.password.$error" style="color:maroon" role="alert">
        <div ng-show="login.$submitted" ng-message="required">You did not enter a field</div>
        <div ng-show="login.$submitted" ng-message="minlength">Your field is too short</div>
    </div>
```